# C - Getting Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Tags: c, tree, segmentation-fault

I just started learning trees and want to implement it.this code compiles but after running i get segmentation fault.I have

**There are 2 functions**

***1."new" This will create a new node to add to the tree***

***2."insert" This will insert data to tree and this is a recursive function***

***I just want to check that data is storing so i tried to print the value in the root node but then i get segmentation fault***

I have checked everything which seems to be correct but don't know what is going wrong

```
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};
struct node* new(int data)
{
    struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));
    newnode->data=data;
    newnode->left=newnode->right=NULL;
    return newnode;
}
struct node* insert(struct node* root,int data)
{
    if(root==NULL)
    {
        new(data);
    }
    else if (data<=root->data)
    {
        root->left =insert(root->left,data);
    }
    else
    {
        root->right=insert(root->right,data);
    }
    return root;
}


void main()
{
    struct node* root = NULL;
    root = insert(root,15);
    root = insert(root,20);

    printf("%d",root->data);
}
```

I expect the output to be 15, but get segmentation fault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't store the data anywhere. Change `new(data);` to `root = new(data);` in the `insert` function.

Another bug is that `struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*))` should be `struct node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(*newnode))`. This both fixes a bug and is better for other reasons.

Also, `void main()` should be `int main()`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the malloc expression. You should malloc struct node and not struct node*. Additionally you should change void main to int main

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you sure want to change `struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node*));` to `struct node* newnode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`, removing the star in the sizeof, otherwise ou get a size of 8 bytes whatever the size of the struct ;)

Then you get a stackoverflow error, but I let you search for that one ;p